# How do I use FPM to generate a Global NPM module as an rpm?

Tags: npm, rpm, fpm

I want to install a node module that I have downloaded like `pm2`and package it as a rpm. When I run the rpm command I want the package installed globally:

example `npm install -g pm2`

Do I create a the rpm from fpm like this?

```
fpm -s npm -t rpm pm2.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fpm will automatically download it from the npm registry. So the following command is enough.

```
fpm -s npm -t rpm pm2
Created package {:path=>"node-pm2-2.7.1-1.x86_64.rpm"}
```